# How can I display a float value to 2 decimal place in JAVA using JOptionpane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I was given a task to calculate the average mark of unknown number of tests in JAVA, I was able to solve the problem but not thoroughly because my output has more than 2 decimal point. May I please be helped to only show my output rounded off to two decimal places. (I am a first year students and I don't know much in JAVA). Here's a snippet of my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class number2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number_Of_Tests = 0;
        int total_marks = 0;
        int mark;
        System.out.print("Enter the test mark: ");
        mark = scan.nextInt();
        while (mark >= 0) {
            number_Of_Tests = number_Of_Tests + 1;
            total_marks = total_marks + mark;
            System.out.print("Enter the test mark: ");
            mark = scan.nextInt();
        }
        float average = total_marks / (float) number_Of_Tests;

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is: "  + average, "AVERAGE",1);
        
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

let's say my input is: 25 , 26 and 28 then 0, my output should be 26.34 but instead I get 26.333334

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class number2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number_Of_Tests = 0;
        int total_marks = 0;
        int mark;
        System.out.print("Enter the test mark: ");
        mark = scan.nextInt();
        while (mark >= 0) {
            number_Of_Tests = number_Of_Tests + 1;
            total_marks = total_marks + mark;
            System.out.print("Enter the test mark: ");
            mark = scan.nextInt();
        }
        float average = total_marks / (float) number_Of_Tests;

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is: " +"% .2f" + average, "AVERAGE",1);
        
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You might also consider something like [Java – Display double in 2 decimal places](https://mkyong.com/java/java-display-double-in-2-decimal-points/) or any of the other numerous examples which are around.  The question is not unique nor is it uncommon.  Due diligence is an expectation - if you've done research, show us what you've learnt and reasons why it's not working for you - otherwise, we're wasting each others time

Answer (score 0):

The first example is a formatter that always produces two decimal places. The second one only produces as many decimal places (up to 2) as needed. Usage: `DF_TWOPLACES.format(average);`

```
final private static DecimalFormat DF_TWOPLACES = new DecimalFormat("0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
final private static DecimalFormat DF_TWOPLACES = new DecimalFormat("0.##", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
```